# Python 3 - Only iterate files that are currently open

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop, iterator

I have two files open in system. The user gives some input, and then the script chooses which file to close. **I must close one of the files.**

However, I have a for loop later on. Since I do not know which one of the files will stay open, and I need to iterate over the rows and columns of one of them, I was wondering if there was a way in which I could dynamically place an iterator (Which would be the file).

Here's the code:

```
with open("file1.csv","r") as a, open ("file2.csv","r") as b:

read_file_no_1 = csv.reader(a); read_file_no_2 = csv.reader(b)

Question=input(Questions[0]).title()
if Question =='something': read_file_no_1.close()
elif Question == 'something_else': read_file_no_2.close()
else: print("Nul")

for i,x,y in zip(range(1,23),read_file_no_2,_file_no_1):        
    Question=input(Questions[i].format(Question,x))
    if any(iterator in Question.split() for iterator in (x,y)):
        print(Question)
    else:
        print("{} {}".format(str(Question),"unknown")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Master-chip

**Edit:**

I've uploaded the entire code. It's not pretty, it's meant to be a proof of concept.

Comment: I don't understand your zip logic at all, what are `read_file_no_2` nand `read_file_no_1`?

Comment: That's not "the code". It's **part** of the code. I don't see any file there, nor operations to close a file. Please provide a more complete example of what you are doing, your attempted solution and how it "doesn't work".

Comment: read_file_no_1 and 2 are the files. The range part is just for it to pick a corresponding element from a list.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham The script works with objects.

Comment: So the user picks a file and you want to close it and iterate over the other?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Pretty much. The user gives a keyword, and if it matches the first line in one of my files, the other file is closed, and I want the script to iterate over the still open file. If neither file has the keyword, then it should use a third file, but I can code that myself.

Comment: assign `read_file = read_file_no_1` or `read_file = read_file_no_2` in `if ... elif ... else: ...` after you have closed the other file. Then you have the reference to the remaining open file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only create the csv object after the user chooses:

```
with open("file1.csv","r") as a, open ("file2.csv","r") as b:
    Question=input(Questions[0]).title()
    if Question =='something':
        r = csv.reader(b)
        a.close()
    elif Question == 'something_else': 
        b.close()
        r = csv.reader(a)
    else: 
         r = csv.reader(other)

    for i,x,y in zip(range(1,23), r):
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: No worries,  you could use logic like  `if a.closed()` but it is a lot simpler just to only create one reader object